# ERROR 5292 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error from long time and I didn't understand what to do. I try to fix it by adding dependencies. But It's not working and giving same error again and again. Please help me. Here is my log.

```
18:36:52.182 [Thread-0] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created 
RestartClassLoader 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@2e89701c

2022-03-14 18:36:52.931  INFO 5292 --- [  restartedMain] com.nominajava.NominaJavaApplication     
: Starting NominaJavaApplication using Java 1.8.0_251 on DESKTOP-G2A4MMS with PID 5292 
(C:\Users\AlejandroPC\Desktop\Infocent\Backend\Nomina V11 backend\semilla-nomina-java-

v11\nomina-java\target\classes started by AlejandroPC in C:\Users\AlejandroPC\Desktop\Infocent\Backend\Nomina V11 backend\semilla-nomina-java-v11)
2022-03-14 18:36:52.932  INFO 5292 --- [  restartedMain] com.nominajava.NominaJavaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-14 18:36:53.048  INFO 5292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\AlejandroPC\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\21.3.0.0\ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/AlejandroPC/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/21.3.0.0/oraclepki.jar
2022-03-14 18:36:53.048  INFO 5292 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-03-14 18:36:54.497 ERROR 5292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.nominajava.NominaJavaApplication.main(NominaJavaApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2022-03-14 18:36:54.501  WARN 5292 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.nominajava.NominaJavaApplication.main(NominaJavaApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

4.0.0 org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.0  <java.version>8</java.version> org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nomina-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>nomina-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>nomina-java</name>
    <description>SemillaBackend para iniciar el proyecto</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
<groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.28.0-GA</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                
                 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter` you are missing one or more dependencies in your runtime environment.

Comment: How do I know which ones I am missing?

Comment: do i add this dependency?

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` which will remove the dependencies and with `mvn clean verify` it will download them again. Check if they aren't broken. Which JDK are you using to run this? I would also suggest to remove the `javassist` and `jackson` dependencies (the latter is old and newer ones are added). Finally try without devtools see if that improves things. The dependency should be there through the `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```